# How to change the visibility of a class field or member for Xamarin Android bindings?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I know ways to do this for methods, but none for fields. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
<Java Code>
public class foo
{
    private int var1;

    private int mtd(){
    ---
    }
}
```

If it is a method, I know to track the method and change its visibility by incl the following in the metadata.xml file:
`<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.xxx.xxx']/class[@name='foo']/method[@name=''mtd]" name="visibility">public</attr>`
How to do the same for a member or field?

Answer (score 2):

> I know ways to do this for methods, but none for fields. Any help would be appreciated.

The contents in `Metadata.xml` will be applied to `project folder\obj\api.xml` and in `api.xml` fields are defined like below:

MyClass.java:

```
package com.winffee.libs;

public class MyClass {
    public int abc;
    public int myMethod() {
        return 0;
    }
}

<field deprecated="not deprecated" final="false" name="abc" static="false" 
    transient="false" type="int" type-generic-aware="int" visibility="public" volatile="false">
```

So, you can define following codes in `Metadata.xml` to modify the Visiblity of `abc` field:

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.winffee.libs']/class[@name='MyClass']/field[@name='abc']" name="visibility">private</attr>
```

Comment: Thanks @elvis. I had tried that but had it not been for a typo.

Comment: What do you mean by `had it not been for a typo`?